# Queue not adding objects - C++ 11

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, queue

I have two custom classes, `Passenger` and `Elevator` contained in the **`Passenger.h`** header file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Passenger
{
    public:

    explicit Passenger(int startTime, int startFloor, int endFloor, int waitTime){
        this->startTime = startTime;
        this->startFloor = startFloor;    
        this->endFloor = endFloor;
        this->waitTime = waitTime;
    }//end constructor

    void increaseWait(int increase){
        this->waitTime += increase;
    }

    int getWait(){
        return this->waitTime;
    }

    int startTime, startFloor, endFloor, waitTime;

}; //end passenger


class Elevator
{
    public:

    explicit Elevator(string the){
        status = "STOPPED";
        passengerCount = 0;
        name = the;        
    }//end constructor

    int addtoQueue(Passenger person){
        if (this->passengerCount < 8){
            this->pickupQueue.push(person);
            return 0;
        }else{
            cout << "Error -- full" << endl;
            return 1;
        } //end

    } //end addtoQueue

    void changePassengerCount(int change){
        passengerCount += change;
    }

    string getStatus(){
        return status;
    }

    void setStatus(string status){
        status = status;
    }

    void addStop(int location){
        stops.push(location);
    }

    int getStops(){
        return stops.size();
    }

    string getName(){
        return name;
    }

    int getRoute(){
        return stops.front();
    }

    bool checkCount(){
        if (passengerCount > 8){
            return false;
        }else{
            return true;
        }
    }

    int printCount(){
        return passengerCount;
    }

    void printQueue(){
        queue<int> copy = stops;

        while(!copy.empty()){
            cout << copy.front() << " ";
            copy.pop();
        }

        cout << endl;
    }

    private:
    string status;
    queue<Passenger> pickupQueue;
    int passengerCount;
    queue<int> stops;
    string name;

}; //end passenger
```

I am reading a `csv` file into a `vector` of `Passenger` objects, and then what I want to do is fill some `queue` objects in each `Elevator` object with those `Passenger` objects. However, it seems as though none of the objects in the `Elevator` class are actually updating. For example, `passengerCount` and `Queue Size` never go above one. I cannot figure out why.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
#include "Passenger.h"
using namespace std;

int time = 0;

int main(){
    vector<Passenger> passengers;
    Elevator elevatorOne = Elevator("elevatorOne");
    Elevator elevatorTwo = Elevator("elevatorTwo");
    Elevator elevatorThree = Elevator("elevatorThree");
    Elevator elevatorFour = Elevator("elevatorFour");
    vector<Elevator> elevators;
    elevators.push_back(elevatorOne);
    elevators.push_back(elevatorTwo);
    elevators.push_back(elevatorThree);
    elevators.push_back(elevatorFour);

    // Code removed when building the vector of passengers by reading in the csv

    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < passengers.size(); i++){
        //cout << "Currently evaluating passenger: " << i << endl;
        for (Elevator currElevator : elevators){
            // If the elevator hasn't moved
            // This is one of three logic checks, but the others have been removed at the request of SO users
            if(currElevator.getStatus().compare("STOPPED") == 0 && currElevator.getStops() == 0 && currElevator.checkCount() == true){                
                // Add the passenger's end floor to the current elevator's queue
                cout << "adding passenger " << i << " to elevator: " << currElevator.getName() << " because of condition 1 " << endl;
                currElevator.addStop(passengers[i].endFloor);
                currElevator.changePassengerCount(1);
                cout << "Queue Size: " << currElevator.getStops() << endl;
                cout << "Passenger Count: " << currElevator.printCount() << endl;
                if(passengers[i].endFloor > currElevator.getRoute()){
                    currElevator.setStatus("MOVING UP");
                } else{
                    currElevator.setStatus("MOVING DOWN");
                }

                break;                     
            } //end if

            else{
                // If none of these conditions match, move on to the next elevator
                continue;
            } //end else
        } //end looping through elevators
    } //end looping through passengers
} //end main
```

I am getting results like:

```
adding passenger 0 to elevator: elevatorOne because of condition 1
Queue Size: 1
Passenger Count: 1
adding passenger 1 to elevator: elevatorOne because of condition 1
Queue Size: 1
Passenger Count: 1
adding passenger 2 to elevator: elevatorOne because of condition 1
Queue Size: 1
```

But would expect to see:

```
adding passenger 0 to elevator: elevatorOne because of condition 1
Queue Size: 1
Passenger Count: 1
adding passenger 1 to elevator: elevatorOne because of condition 1
Queue Size: 2
Passenger Count: 2
adding passenger 2 to elevator: elevatorOne because of condition 1
Queue Size: 3
Passenger Count: 3
```

etc

Comment: Too much code. Make a [mcve]

Comment: I wanted to post less, but I think it is important to show the `vector` of `Passengers` being created. Should I not?

Comment: So you're saying that, to reproduce the error, every single piece of functionality in the above code needs to be present? It's a bug that relies on some interaction between all those bits of logic? You've tried to eliminate parts of the above code from blame, and the bug goes away if even one of them is removed? Because, if not, it's not a [mcve]. We get thousands of posts a day. _You_ narrow it down, _we'll_ fix it. :) Good luck.

Comment: That is correct. In order to replicate the error, it is important to understand both of the custom classes, since that is where the error is arising; inside of those classes. Therefore, the header file must be present. In the main function, it is probably important (I would think it is, if I were answering the question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apologies for a dumb question.

Replacing:

```
for (Elevator currElevator : elevators){
```

with:

```
for (int j = 0; j < elevators.size(); j++){
```

and all calls for `currElevator` to `elevators[j]` fixed the problem.

I'm not sure, at this time, *why* that would have an effect, but will update this answer with further research.

**UPDATE**

Per Corristo:
The reason this happened is that `currElevator` inside the range-based for loop is a copy of the elevator in the `elevators` vector. If you declare your range-based for loop as for (`Elevator& currElevator : elevators`) it should work because now `currElevator` is a reference to an element in the `elevators` vector instead of a copy.

Comment: The reason this happened is that `currElevator` inside the range-based `for` loop is a copy of the elevator in the `elevators` vector. If you declare your range-based for loop as `for (Elevator& currElevator : elevators)` it shoud work because now `currElevator` is a reference to an element in the `elevators` vector instead of a copy.